# Append to existing REACT Form template property values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, templates, properties

New to REACT and I am trying to determine, if a REACT Form controls property value can be appended to add additional functionality.

I created a validation template, if you will, that uses the property **validation**. This done so all the validation code does not have to be typed out for each date control that needs validating.

```
export const date_max_validation = {
    name: 'dateEntry',
    label: 'Date Entry',
    type: 'date',
    id: 'dateEntry',
    placeholder: 'Enter or select a date...',
    style: DATE_STYLE,
    validate: validateFormInput,
    validation: {
        required: {
            value: true,
            message: 'A valid date is required!',
        },
        isDate: {
          message: 'Not a valid date!',  
        },
        isDateMax: {
            value: 36525, // value in days
            message: 'Date must be less than 100 years ago!',
        },
    },
}
```

The template works perfectly but there are times when I need to add extra validation to the control and want to be able to on the Form append the additional validation to the end of the current validation. Right now, the code below, just overwrites what's in the templates **validation** property.

```
<FormTextInput {...date_max_validation} 
     label="What day do you leave?"
     id={FormFieldId.StartDate}
     name={FormFieldId.StartDate}
     value={values[FormFieldId.StartDate]}
     handleInputChange={this.onChangeInput}
     validation= {{
          validate: {
          value: () => isLessOrEqual(this.state.values[FormFieldId.StartDate], this.state.values[FormFieldId.EndDate]),
          message: 'Start date must be less than or equal to end date.'
          }
     }}
/>
```

Is there any way to be able to append that extra property validation to the end of current validation stored in the template?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the **append** work by adding a spread operator to the end of validate which points to the template and then to its validation property.

```
...date_max_validation.validation
```

The code now looks like this

```
<FormTextInput {...date_max_validation} 
    label="What day do you leave?"
    id={FormFieldId.StartDate}
    name={FormFieldId.StartDate}
    value={values[FormFieldId.StartDate]}
    handleInputChange={this.onChangeInput}
    validation= {{
         validate: {
         value: () => isLessOrEqual(this.state.values[FormFieldId.StartDate], this.state.values[FormFieldId.EndDate]),
         message: 'Start date must be less than or equal to end date.'
         }, ...date_max_validation.validation
    }}
/>
```